# Using Timthumb file in xslt

Tags: php, xml, xslt, timthumb

i am having trouble in figuring out how i can use tim thumb for cropping image in xslt
For example below code is in php :

```
<img src="include/timthumb.php?src=http://localhost/testdata/1830censusfiscalchart.jpg&w=400&h=200 "  />
```

my question is how can i write above code in xsl , i tried different ways but it keep     throwing me errors.

Comment: Could you show the code you have tried already, and give a bit more detail about exactly what errors are being thrown. Thank you!

Comment: i m keep getting this error:  XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ampersands (`&`) in an attribute that is being output by XSLT, they you need to 'escape' them as `&amp;` so that the XML is well-formed. Something like this:

```
<img src="include/timthumb.php?
          src=http://localhost/testdata/1830censusfiscalchart.jpg&amp;w=400&amp;h=200 "  />
```